# Need help inserting data into html

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

I want to insert a value of a Javascript variable into html file. But the output is blank. The desired data is stored in the variable but the output in html file is blank.

My htmll file

```html
<div class="student-info">
     <p>Name: Anon</p>
     <p>Registration Number:</p>

<script src="resources/js/data_inp.js">document.write(regno)</script>
<script src="resources/js/data_inp.js"></script>
```

my data_inp.js file

```js
//get regno
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    if (user) {
        console.log(user);
        var email = firebase.auth().currentUser.email;
        var regno = email.substring(0, email.length - 8);
        //email is eg. 1234@xyz.com where 1234 is regno so I used this method to separate the regno
        console.log(regno);
    }
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want to keep all the javascript in one file and keep all the html in one file and target specific elements using document.getElementById()

html

```
<div class="student-info">
                        <p>Name: Anon</p>
                        <p id=registrationNumber>Registration Number:</p>
</div>
<script src="resources/js/data_inp.js"></script>
```

javascript

```
//get regno
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    if (user) {
        console.log(user);
        var email = firebase.auth().currentUser.email;
        var regno = email.substring(0, email.length - 8);
        //email is eg. 1234@xyz.com where 1234 is regno so I used this method to separate the regno
        console.log(regno);

        var myElement = document.getElementById("registrationNumber");
        var newcontent = document.createElement('div');
        myElement.append(newcontent);
        newcontent.innerHTML = regno;
    }
});
```

Comment: aren't you missing a `myElement.append(newcontent)`?

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML remove the `script` and make a `span` with an `id`, then target the `innerText` of the span.

```
<p>Registration Number: <span id="dynamic-value"></span></p>
```

Then in your js,

```
document.getElementById('dynamic-value').innerText = regno
```